# Any way to access StackExchange from a text only browser?

Tags: authentication, links

I have a very slow computer and spend most of my time without a graphical environment. StackExchange doesn't let me log in using Links saying that my "request could not be completed because it looks suspicious." Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: I get the same error both with `links2` and with `lynx`. This looks like a bug, I would recommend you post a question and tag it as bug on [so.meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I have had good luck with `edbrowse`.

Comment: Maybe [Netsurf](http://www.netsurf-browser.org) is an alternative to console browsers. It even.has a.fbdev front-end.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Natively, it *should* work - though SE uses a lot of modern stuff on their website, and obviously it isn't working for you or terdon, as per the comments. However there's a site called [column 80](http://www.column80.com/) ( [stackapps link](https://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu) ) that might let you read, SOFU and other sites on SE. That said, a terminal accessible SE chat would be ace ;).

This question looks like this on w3m

[image: If you're looking at this, it is bob's fault cause he wants more recursion]

Comment: Nice one, +1 one for sheer geekiness! As far as I can tell, it's only the identification that doesn't work, I can see the sites OK but can't log in. This solution makes the sites look better but still does not appear to enable logging in, they seem to have simply deactivated the login link.

Comment: This is pretty darn cool. Never knew about the site

Comment: Yeah, this is read only - I think its simply an officially sanctioned site scrape that reformats the pages.

Comment: Link to **stackapps** for your reference: http://stackapps.com/questions/542/column-80-plain-text-optimised-sofu

Comment: So THATS where I remembered it from. I think I know the guy who wrote it from chat too... oops ;p